# Prove that if $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then every divisor $d|mn$ has a unique form $d=ab$ such that $a|n$ and $b|m$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I can see why this is true. I have a problem with formality or with explaining certain things properly.

An attempt: suppose there are two forms $d=a_na_m=b_nb_m$ such that $a_n,b_n|n,a_m,b_m|m$ but $a_i\ne b_i$. Therefore, in $d'$s prime factorization, WLOG, there is a prime $p$(not 1) dividing n that is in $b_n$'s prime factorization but not in $a_n$'s. However, $a_m$ divides $m$.

$p$ could not be excluded as being a factor in $d'$s prime factorization. Therefore it is in $a_m$'s prime factorization, contradicting that facts that $(m,n)=1$ and $p\ne 1$.

I would appreciate your criticism. I would accept it as an answer as well.

Comment: You've successfully proven uniqueness, but you have to still prove existence.

Comment: You're correct. I shall try proving existence.

Comment: Assume that $d$ is a divisor of $mn$ and $d=ab$ with $a$ dividing $m$ and $b$ dividing $n$, what are $gcd(d,m)$ and $gcd(d,n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. For existence, observe that $d=(d,mn)$ and since $(m,n)=1$ you know $d=(d,mn)=(d,m)(d,n)$.

By definition of $\gcd$ we have $(d,m)\mid m$ and $(d,n)\mid n$.

Comment: I never knew this lemma. I will try to prove it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's enough to observe that $a=(n,d),b=(m,d)$.